# SVG Fill Color Hover Transitions Not Animating

Tags: css, wordpress, svg

I have [transition animations on an SVG](http://brandonmoner.me/) and everything is working fine except for the fill colors of .logo-square and .logo-bg. The color just changes without any pretty transitions. I definitely have it listed as a transitio, and [it works in my pen](http://cdpn.io/jotCs).

Can someone lend a hand as to what I’m maybe missing?

Comment: The animations at both links seem to be working for me in Chrome. Or at least they both behave the same.

Comment: Ok so you can actually see the transition, and not just the animation, in Chrome? Because on my side it just looks like the color is snapping on when i hover, and snapping off when I leave the area. There's nothing smooth about the transition from the grey to the violet.

OSX 10.9.2 / Chrome 34.0.1847.131 / Safari 7.0.3 (9537.75.14) / FireFox 28.0

Comment: Yes colour transition is smooth for me on Chrome 34, FF 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was how Safari renders and behaves with certain CSS properties in regards to SVG. I've since abandoned this way in favor of a easier image hover transition.